# Iterator error C2440

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, iterator

I am trying to make a small hashing program but there is an error I don't know how to deal with. The problem is on the arrow and here is the error:

> Error  1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_String_const_iterator<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' to 'std::_String_iterator<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>'

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

unsigned long hash(const string& str);

int main()
{
   long out;
   string word;
   word = "about";
   out = hash(word) % 255;
   cout << out;
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}


unsigned long djb2(const string& str)
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;

    for(string::iterator it=str.begin();it!=str.end();it++)  //<~~~~~~~~~~
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + *it; /* hash * 33 + character */

    return hash;
 }
```

Comment: Cannot convert **_String_const_iterator** to **_String_iterator**. Make sure you read your error messages thoroughly, they are your friend!

Comment: There is no definition for `unsigned long hash(const string& str);`. On top of that, you've named your functions and variables the same, which is not so great. I think the `djb2()` function is supposed to be `hash()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a `const_iterator`:

```
 for( std::string::const_iterator it=str.begin();it!=str.end();it++)
```

since your argument to the function is `const string &str` the `iterator` has to agree.

Comment: i replaced interator with const_iterator and now there are 2 errors. 1: Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "unsigned long __cdecl hash(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?hash@@YAKABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function _main hashtest1.obj hashtest1  and 2 : Error 2 fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals C:\Users\Manos\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\hashtest1\Debug\hashtest1.exe hashtest1

Comment: @user2145433 Aesthete is correct, you do not define the function `hash` and you should usually avoid using the same name like that.

Comment: By the way with this function for hashing. How long should be the array of objects? ( i will have to put in there all the words(one time each word) of 30 txts. each txt is a story) So there will be looots of words and i want to avoid some collisions. If the array will be of 255 size is good? or should it be more?

Comment: @user2145433 Design of the hash function is outside the scope of this question and would require more space then a comment. I think Code Review site may be more appropriate for this question http://codereview.stackexchange.com/